# How should I ask a question about the use of block comments in Ruby?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions, opinion-based

I would like to know whether the use of block comments in Ruby is a good programming practice. What are the pros and cons of block comments compared to line comments?

Before even posting this question, I think that this question is likely to get closed as mostly opinion based. **How can the question be changed to a form that is less opinion based, and more likely to remain open?**

**DETAILS:**

Block comments in Ruby have this form:

```ruby
=begin
...some 
multiline
text...
=end
```

Note that I am aware of the following sources, which mostly argue for the line comments and against the block comments in Ruby:

- [Class: RuboCop::Cop::Style::BlockComments — Documentation for rubocop (1.21.0)](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/BlockComments)
- [Block Comments are a Bad Idea, by Troels Henriksen](https://futhark-lang.org/blog/2017-10-10-block-comments-are-a-bad-idea.html)
- [Hacker News: Block Comments Are a Bad Idea](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15440166)

Comment: Maybe CodeReview.se is a better venue? You could show ruby code with Block Comments and then ask if the readability of that code is acceptable / conforms to industry standard.

Comment: @rene Thank you! I will try CodeReview.se. Is there a way to salvage the question for SO, though? There are several great Ruby programmers that use SO but, unfortunately, not CodeReview.se.

Comment: How and why to use a particular type of comment will always be opinion based, they don't make a difference to the compiler, so the only benefit is to the user and their preference.

Comment: The question as shown is inherently opinion based and I would need to do a lot of brain gymnastics to turn it into something that isn't recognized as such. The only chance you have is when there is a problem with (not) using block commands, for example if your IDE or static code analyzer chokes on it. But that will not answer if it is a good practice. At best that will be mentioned in a sub-conclusion on an awesome answer.

Comment: "SEE ALSO:" Please don't give links to entire other pages without explaining what is relevant & why, and normally include via quote/paraphrase any relevant content necessary to ask your question. Don't expect us to read entire pages & then try to guess at figuring that out. Also where is your research effort shown at answering yourself?

Comment: @philipxy Do you mean research effort at answering the **meta** question, or answering the **block comments** question "within the question"?

Comment: I commented re this meta question. (But it applies to any site & post.) Note that your edit doesn't achieve what that comment suggests. PS Please clearly say what was the content from your SO question & block quote it as the quote that it is (if that's what it is, and otherwise I don't know what it is, so again, please rewrite to be clear) since"DETAILS:" does not communicate either the start or the end of that being that part of this meta post you are talking about.

Comment: @philipxy I have not asked a question on SO, but was originally planning to reword it somehow and post it. Not anymore, it seems like SO will not accept it. So there is no "content from your SO question" to block quote it, bc there is no SO question and now it appears that there should not be. Perhaps I should clarify that in the OP. BTW, after getting all the feedback, I plan to follow the advice from *rene* and *RyanM*.

Comment: @philipxy Re: *Also where is your research effort shown at answering yourself? * I read the obvious [ask] and [help] pages, but could not quickly find what I was looking for. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, for my future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @rene Thank you for the help! After substantial refactoring, posted the question on CodeReview.se, and it has not been closed - yet: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268342/migration-in-a-bioinformatics-application-that-changes-a-column-name-and-explain?noredirect=1#comment529153_268342

Answer (score 4):

A question about the use of block comments from a style perspective would be on-topic at Software Engineering—see [Are coding style questions that deal with language-specific features allowed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1179/6573) on their meta.

...**but** note [this answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7791/6573) to *Are questions about good coding style on topic?*:

> Don't ask *"which is better"* or *"is this a good idea"* without explaining what "good" or "better" specifically means, in a way that isn't a tautology ([**"best practice"**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937) is not any better than "better.")

So the question you've asked will likely need to be more specific about what you're wanting to know about.  There is more good advice in the linked answer.

Comment: see also [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260) at their meta